# Interpolating variables within already interpolated strings in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interpolation

I have the following arrangement to fetch helptexts from a single Coffeescript file.

Coffeescript:

```
help.ex: '{{example.variable}} identifies enterprise data centers'
```

HAML:

```
%example-directive(attr='{{help.ex}}')
```

Now the example.variable is accessible but it is not getting interpolated on the view. This I guess is happening because the string as a whole is getting interpolated and compile is not running on the variables within. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$interpolate` service:

```
var exp = $interpolate(attrs.attr) // interpolate your attriubte
var interpolated = exp(scope) // evaluate it with the scope variable
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/20NwgAdleCFDeTJaQJKb?p=preview)